# Get data on basis of Categories django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

(Any suggestion would be highly appreciated) I have model of Articles like

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
    articlename = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE , blank=True, null=True)
```

Now I want to get data in a form like  "Every Category will have all articles in form of objects from database"

for example I have 2 articles ,  1 is "article1  having cat1" and 2nd "article2 having cat2" Now I want to get data like this   `data:[ cat1:[{article1},{}] , cat2:[{article2}] ]`     is there any `group by categories` like thing in django ??  till  now I have tried this code

```
order_article = OrderArticle.objects.filter(order__order_number=id ,order__restaurant=restid) 
        samearticle=[]
        for order_obj in order_article:
            if : #will check if article having cat already been created
                category={}
                category[order_obj.article.category.name]=order_obj
                samearticle.append(order_obj.article.category.name)
            else:
                samearticle[order_obj.article.category.name].append(order_obj)
```

Comment: If I understood correctly you want all categories and all article that belong to each category. Something like this ```{'cat1':[article1, article2], 'cat2': [article4, article5]}``` Is it correct?

Comment: @BinitSingh  yes exactly

Comment: @BinitSingh  I am unable to serlize this

Comment: @BinitSingh   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59974521/how-to-serialize-manual-created-object-in-django-rest-framework    can you check this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your Categories model has a name field. 
You can actually loop over categories and get all related articles using [related object reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#related-objects-reference)

```
order_article_list = OrderArticle.objects.filter(order__order_number=id ,order__restaurant=restid) 
data = {}
for order_article in order_article_list:
  data[order_article.article.category.name] = order_article.article.category.articles_set.all()
```

Comment: Actually here is minor issue , I get just order id , On which bases I ma getting Articles , Now Every article have category . I am queryring where I get ordered article   order_article = OrderArticle.objects.filter(order__order_number=id ,order__restaurant=restid)

Comment: bro let me check

Comment: thanks bro . Now I have accurate data but why Serializes not accepting this ? and giving error  "TypeError: 'OrderArticle' object is not iterable"

Comment: @gamer Great. Please accept the answer. Is the serialization problem resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```html
def index(request, category_slug=None):
    category = None
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    if category_slug:
        category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
        articles = articles.filter(category=categories)
    context = {
        'articles': articles,
        'categories': categories,
        'category': category,
    }
```

Then in your view

```html
{% regroup articles by category as articles_by_category %}
  {% for c in products_by_category %}
  
  {% endfor %}
```